# Play akka microservice as multi project

Tags: playframework, sbt, akka, microservices, multi-project

I am learning about microservices. For demonstration purposes I want to combine a frontend: `play` with some backend services: `Akka`. SBT`s`multi-project` compilation should be well suited for this. However I face some problems:

- The main class cannot be found - even if I navigate into the correct sub-module.
- The dependencies are not resolved, even though they seem to be defined correctly.

To follow along:
https://github.com/dataplayground/microservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Dependencies must be explicitly imported as such:

```
lazy val backend = (project in file(".")).aggregate(api)

lazy val api = project.in(file("modules/api"))
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= backendCommon)

lazy val backendCommon = Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.11",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.3.11" % "test",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test")
```